# Scala sys.process nonzero exit values

Tags: scala, process

On comparing different files

```
import sys.process._"
"diff data.txt myFile.txt" !
```

the exit code proves nonzero as expected,

```
< 1
---
> 123
res1: Int = 1
```

However on trying to gather the actual differences

```
val d = "diff data.txt myFile.txt" !!

java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:132)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
  ... 33 elided
```

To ask how to fetch the differences into a `String` (given small files) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you need to use the `lineStream_!` method, and not the `!`. With the line stream which is the output of the `diff` command, you can do whatever you want: print it, convert it to list, to array, or whatever else you need.

```
val st = "diff input.txt output.txt" lineStream_!
// now st is a Stream[String]
println(st.mkString("\n"))
```

**EDIT:** I believe that method was called before `lines_!`. Now it's deprecated. Just in case you are using an old Scala version.

Comment: thanks. had to do the same for specific usage of `wget`